# Error when calculating rolling pairwise correlations in R using rollapply

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame in R

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18352, 18382, 18413, 18443, 
18474, 18505, 18535, 18566, 18596, 18627), class = "Date"), `Item 1` = c(1.51832975855564, 
0.37616251475745, 0.235532024125229, 0.709469777058103, 1.02933768602063, 
1.32152918133017, 1.40923563776068, 1.20359679507398, 1.16086943030891, 
1.28886722075181), `Item 2` = c(2.14545986795986, 2.96713831051805, 
3.07870599806344, 3.23176921561792, 4.15485377279825, 4.90266273750217, 
5.01422259880169, 4.41057753970351, 4.99683267473077, 5.26300032931175
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to calculate rolling correlations between the two columns in my dataframe. When I try to use `rollapply` like below

```
correlation <-  rollapply(data, width=3, function(x) cor(x[,2],x[,3]), by.column=FALSE)
```

I get the following error. I've tried setting the two columns to numeric format using `as.numeric`, however that didn't solve the issue. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
Error in cor(x[, 2], x[, 3]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `rollapply` coerces the data to a matrix and since the first column of `data` is not numeric it winds up passing a character matrix.  Omit the first column and it will work.  Also you may or may not want to use `rollapplyr` with an r on the end in order to use a right aligned window (the default is centered) and fill = NA (the default is no filling) to fill out the result to have the same length as the number of rows in data.  We have shown those here just in case that was what you wanted.

```
cor2 <- function(x, ...) cor(x[, 1], x[, 2], ...) # scalar cor of 1st 2 cols
rollapplyr(data[-1], 3, cor2, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
## [1]         NA         NA -0.9999543  0.7475923  0.8759702  0.9994088
## [7]  0.9947371  0.9652525  0.3777091  0.4791595
```

**2)** or if you wanted a centered window with no NA filling then use `rollapply` with no r on the end and omit the fill= argument.

```
rollapply(data[-1], 3, cor2, by.column = FALSE)
## [1] -0.9999543  0.7475923  0.8759702  0.9994088  0.9947371  0.9652525  0.3777091
## [8]  0.4791595
```

**3)** Another possibility is to use a zoo object as the input giving the displayed zoo object as output.  zoo object stores the time index as an attribute rather than a column so we can just pass it as is.

```
z <- read.zoo(data)
rollapply(z, 3, cor2, by.column = FALSE)
## 2020-04-30 2020-05-31 2020-06-30 2020-07-31 2020-08-31 2020-09-30 2020-10-31 
## -0.9999543  0.7475923  0.8759702  0.9994088  0.9947371  0.9652525  0.3777091 
## 2020-11-30 
##  0.4791595
```

### Note

One other point not related to the rolling window is that it appears that the input is using a date equal to the last day of the month to represent year/month and it would be possible to directly represent a year and month without a day using yearmon class.  Such a class represents the date internally as the year + fraction where Jan = 0, Feb = 1/12, ..., Dec = 11/12, displays showing the month and year and would be regularly spaced unlike using dates which are irregularly spaced due to the different number of days in a month.

```
data$Date <- as.yearmon(data$Date)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Date      `Item 1` `Item 2`
   <yearmon>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Mar 2020     1.52      2.15
 2 Apr 2020     0.376     2.97
 3 May 2020     0.236     3.08
 4 Jun 2020     0.709     3.23
 5 Jul 2020     1.03      4.15
 6 Aug 2020     1.32      4.90
 7 Sep 2020     1.41      5.01
 8 Oct 2020     1.20      4.41
 9 Nov 2020     1.16      5.00
10 Dec 2020     1.29      5.26
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll respond this way, as I prefer `slider` (and it would be even safer to use `tsibble` on your dates). Anyway, here's an answer (where you'll need, say, nine observations before calculating a correlation):

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    correl = slider::slide2_dbl(
      .x = `Item 1`, 
      .y = `Item 2`, 
      .f = ~cor(.x, .y), 
      .before = 8L, 
      .complete = TRUE
      )
    )
```

... which produces:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Date       `Item 1` `Item 2` correl
   <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2020-03-31    1.52      2.15 NA    
 2 2020-04-30    0.376     2.97 NA    
 3 2020-05-31    0.236     3.08 NA    
 4 2020-06-30    0.709     3.23 NA    
 5 2020-07-31    1.03      4.15 NA    
 6 2020-08-31    1.32      4.90 NA    
 7 2020-09-30    1.41      5.01 NA    
 8 2020-10-31    1.20      4.41 NA    
 9 2020-11-30    1.16      5.00  0.407
10 2020-12-31    1.29      5.26  0.941
```

That said, you can switch to `complete = FALSE` if you want correlation estimates for earlier dates.